# LinkButton, how prevent double click with "asp:LinkButton" ? or disabled "asp:LinkButton" after first click

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms

I am trying to avoid a double click, that is, the first click can disable the `asp: LinkButton` through the javascript functions, all this is in an `aspx` page.

I have little experience in the front-end, if you can support me I'll thank you.

I tried simply to use: `setAttribute, getElementById, attr`:

```
<div class="modal-footer">
  <div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnBringDataFlow" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-danger" ToolTip="Cancel"
                    OnClick="btnBringDataFlow_Click" OnClientClick="preventDoubleClick()">Bring Data
    </asp:LinkButton>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnCancel" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary" ToolTip="Cancel">Cancel</asp:LinkButton>
  </div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
  function disabledLinkBringDataFlow() {

    document.getElementById('btnBringDataFlow').setAttribute("disabled", "");

    //document.getElementById("btnBringDataFlow").disabled = true;
  }
</script>
```

I hope to disable the `asp: LinkButton` after the first click to avoid double execution of the function.

Answer (score 1):

I think in order for your Javascript method to get the element by ID you'll need to add the `ClientIDMode = "Static"` attribute to your LinkButton control.  The server control will add some text to the control's ID value by default.

```
<asp:LinkButton ClientIDMode="Static" ID="btnBringDataFlow" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-danger" ToolTip="Cancel" OnClick="btnBringDataFlow_Click" OnClientClick="preventDoubleClick()">Bring Data</asp:LinkButton>
```

If you'd like more info on the ClientIDMode property, see: [ClientIDMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Web_UI_Control_ClientIDMode)

Answer (score 1):

`asp:LinkButton` renders an anchor tag. Use `this` keyword to access anchor and its properties:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" />
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="btnBringDataFlow" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-danger" ToolTip="Cancel"
                    OnClientClick="preventDoubleClick(this)">Bring Data
                </asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<script>
    function preventDoubleClick(sender) {
        sender.setAttribute("disabled", "");
    }
</script>
```

If you prefer use inline code `onClienClick="this.setAttribute('disabled', '');"`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone

My solution was the following:

```js
  <script>
        function preventDoubleClick() {
             $("#" + '<%= btnBringDataFlow.ClientID %>').addClass("disabled");
                $("#" + '<%= btnBringDataFlow.ClientID %>').attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }
    </script>
```

```html
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnBringDataFlow" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-danger" ToolTip="Cancel" OnClick="btnBringDataFlow_Click" OnClientClick="preventDoubleClick()" >Bring Data</asp:LinkButton>
```